# Drop-in of MariaDB triggers removal of needed packages depending mysql-common

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, dependencies, mariadb, apt-get

In Ubuntu (Actually Kubuntu) 15.10 (Wily) attempting to install MariaDB 10.1 all instructions say to first remove *mysql-client* and *mysql-common* packages via *sudo apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common* and passing the -s flag (sudo apt-get -s remove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common) shows that to remove *mysql-common* will also result in several other packages being removed that one would not want gone...

**The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:**
  libarmadillo5 libctemplate2v5 libdap17v5 libdapclient6v5 libdbi-perl libepsilon1 libfreexl1 libgeos-3.5.0 libgeos-c1v5 libhdf4-0-alt libkmlbase1 libkmldom1 libkmlengine1 liblwgeom-2.1.8 libminizip1
  libnetcdf7 libodbc1 libogdi3.2 libopenjp2-7 libpq5 libproj9 libspatialite7 libsuperlu4 libterm-readkey-perl liburiparser1 libvsqlitepp3v5 mysql-utilities mysql-workbench-data odbcinst
  odbcinst1debian2 proj-bin proj-data python-ecdsa python-mysql.connector python-paramiko python-pexpect python-pyodbc
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.

**The following packages will be REMOVED:**
  accountwizard* akonadi-backend-mysql* akonadi-server* akregator* amarok* amarok-utils* kaddressbook* kdepim-runtime* kmail* knotes* kontact* korganizer* libdbd-mysql-perl* libgdal1i*
  libmysqlclient18* libmysqlcppconn7v5* libqt4-sql-mysql* libqt5sql5-mysql* mysql-client* mysql-client-5.6* mysql-common* mysql-workbench*

So as you can see, things like *kaddressbook*, *knotes*, *mysql-workbench*, *etc.* I don't know if I should just leave *mysql-common* and install *mariadb-common* alongside it or if there are any other options to perform the drop-in replacement without removing all that depends on *mysql-common*.

**edit:** I did *apt-cache policy mysql-common* which showed:

```
mysql-common:
  Installed: 5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1
  Candidate: 10.1.13+maria-1~wily
  Version table:
     10.1.13+maria-1~wily 0
        500 http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.6.25-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
```

So then I tried *sudo apt-get update* which I hoped would replace *mysql-common* with *mariadb-common* but it didn't.

Comment: Updated to show package policy and apt-get update attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to remove *mysql-client* and *mysql-server* (If installed), leaving *mysql-common* and then doing *apt-get update* and *apt-get upgrade* so long as *apt-cache policy mysql-common* shows an upgrade to *mariadb-common*. After that you can install *mariadb-server* as usual with no unintended consequences.